# Number of primitive Dirichlet characters of certain order and of bounded conductor

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-character

Writing $q(\chi)$ for the conductor of a Dirichlet character $\chi$, one can show using Mobius inversion that
$$\#\{\text{$\chi$ primitive Dirichlet characters}\,:\,q(\chi)\leq Q\}\sim cQ^2.$$
My question is how to find an asymptotic expression for the cardinality of the more specific set
$$\{\text{$\chi$ primitive Dirichlet characters}\,:\,\chi^d=1,\,q(\chi)\leq Q\}$$
for a fixed $d\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$. By Lemma 9.3 in Montgomery and Vaughan's *Multiplicative number theory*, it suffices to count only those characters $\chi$ in the above set modulo a prime power, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck, because Theorem 2 in [this paper of Finch, Sebah, and myself](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Egerg/papers/downloads/RUNM.pdf) gives an asymptotic formula for exactly this quantity. The order of magnitude is $Q(\log Q)^{\tau(d)-2}$, where $\tau(d)$ is the number of positive divisors of $d$; the leading constant is complicated but is given explicitly in the paper. (Note that there is a difference between "$\chi^d=1$" and "$\chi$ has order $d$", but the same asymptotic formula holds for the two cases.)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, this is very helpful!